# Testing validity time of the token

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, testing, junit

I want to test my token's validity time and when i wrote the code and restart the server the secret key change. For this reason my tests always fail. How can i fix it?

Here are my isExpired and its aux-method:

```
final Key key = Keys.secretKeyFor(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256); //This key always
// change if i restart server
.
.
.
public boolean isExpired(String token) {
    Claims claims = getClaims(token);
    return claims.getExpiration().after(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
}

private Claims getClaims(String token) {
    return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(key).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to question, but it looks like there might be a bug in that isExpired method. The method is returning `true` if the claim's expiration is _after_ the current time. The correct behavior is probably to return `true` if the claim's expiration is _before_ the current time.

Comment: I did not realize it. When use the isExpired, i basically use its reverse form for this reason my code works fine but for readability i should fix it. Thanks.@dnault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly you did not provide any information about the lib you are using to generate the `Key`. By the API I guess it`s [this one](https://github.com/jwtk/jjw)?

As written in the [doc](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt#secret-keys) you can see why you get another Key every time you run your test.

> Under the hood, JJWT uses the JCA provider's KeyGenerator to create a secure-random key with the correct minimum length for the given algorithm.

So it is the normal behaviour of the library to generate a new random `Key` every time `Keys.secretKeyFor` is invoked.

Besides this general information there is also the solution to your problem:

> If you need to save this new SecretKey, you can Base64 (or Base64URL) encode it:

```
String secretString = Encoders.BASE64.encode(key.getEncoded());
```

If you want to use the same `Key` every time your tests run you should deserialize the same Base64 String before each test.
For deserialization you can use the `Base64Decoder` and pass the `byte[]` into `SecretKey.hmacShaKeyFor`-Method.
Your code should look somethin like this.

```
byte[] decodedKey = Decoders.BASE64.decode("Your_Base64_key");
SecretKey key = SecretKey.hmacShaKeyFor(decodedKey);
```

I would suggest you store your Base64 encoded `Secret` in the resources Folder of your Test Sourceroot.

---

Also I would recommend you to pass the current Date into your `isExpired`-Method because otherwise your Tests are dependent from the systems current time.
You should try to eliminate all dynamic things in your Unit Test. Otherwise they will become brittle and start failing at 'random'.